# How to find distance between a zipcode and a dataframe containing a list of zipcodes?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggmap

I am trying to do so with ggmap but I cannot figure out how to run it for all zipcodes in my list...

```
library(readxl)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)

zip_code_data <- 
  read_excel("D:/Desktop/Institutional Research/Zip code data for study.xlsx")

sapply(zip_code_data2$Zip2, function(x) mapdist('19426', x, mode = 'driving'))

#dataset below, shortened due to character limit, dataset is 1460 entries
zip_code_data2<-data.frame(City = c("Douglassville", "Bartlett", "Harleysville", "Westport", "Clayton"),  
                       Abrv = c("PA", "NJ", "CT", "PA", "NJ"),  
                       State = c("Pennsylvania", "New Jersey", "Connecticut", "Pennsylvania", "New Jersey"),    
                       Zip = c("19380-3306", "08096-3533", "06437-1936", "19540-1100", "08094-4114"), 
                       Zip2 = c("19380", "08096", "06437", "19540", "08094"))
```

Comment: sapply(zip_code_data$Zip, function(x) mapdist('19426', x, mode = 'driving'))

Comment: I tried this but I get the following error:

Comment: Error in `*tmp*`[[c(1, 1)]] : no such index at level 1

Comment: res=sapply(as.vector(zip_code_data$Zip), function(x) mapdist('19426', x, mode = 'driving'))

Comment: John - Whats your function for doing 1x? Max is basically saying write that function wrapped in sapply to run it over all

Comment: The issue has to do with the format of your data structure I guess consider providing a sample

Comment: I need a function that returns the distance in miles and hours from zip code 19426, when i read in a list of zip codes.. I have since updated the code to show my edits as well as the dataframe; when I run each individually it works, but not as a whole list...